# AWS Glue Timeout: Creating External Schema In Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to create an external schema, and my command is as follows. As of course, I have changed the names of the components/items to non-meaningful names just to hide my production values:

```
create external schema sb_external 
from data catalog 
database 'dev' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::490412345678:role/aws-service-role/redshift.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForRedshift'
create external database if not exists;
```

The query is ran in the Redshift database using "psql" CLI from within an EC2 instance. It is a private subnet, while the EC2 instance and the Redshift Database are in 2 different VPCs joined by VPC Peering. On the VPC where we have the EC2 instance, we have a Glue Endpoint.

While I run the above query from the same VPC where I have the Redshift database, I still get an error as follows, even if in the same VPC I have created an Endpoint Interface for Glue.

`Failed to perform AWS request, curlError=Failed to connect to glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out`

With or Without the VPC Endpoint, we have the same error.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So the query is run from Glue right? Same subnet as Redshift? And is it a private subnet?

Comment: @RobertKossendey: The query is ran in the Redshift database using "psql" CLI from within an EC2 instance. I've just updated the original question with this information. It is a private subnet, while the EC2 instance and the Redshift Database are in 2 different VPCs joined by VPC Peering. On the VPC where we have the EC2 instance, we have a Glue Endpoint.

Comment: I don't get why you would need a Glue Endpoint?

Comment: I agree @RobertKossendey: Was just trying if that would help, since in the Security section of AWS documentation I saw that using VPC Endpoints would make sure we are working within the intranet. Please refer here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoint.html.

In any case, with or without the Endpoint we have the same issue.

Comment: So the error needs to be in the route table. Your request goes to a glue url on port 443 although it should go to Redshift. So you need to look into your routing.

Comment: @RobertKossendey: shouldn't the request be going to Glue instead since I am creating a database in Glue Catalog/Metadata and then aiming to use it within Redshift? I agree with you that it has something to do with the Routing or networking settings itself.

Comment: But it is a query that is being executed on the Redshift Cluster, right? So it should go to Redshift first. Redshift does some calls in the background then I assume.

Comment: @RobertKossendey: we have no issues with Redshift as neither the error says so, nor are we seeing any issues with connectivity since I am able to connect to Redshift and perform any other operation! Any ideas?

Comment: Then you are right, the routing from Redshift to Glue fails, while making the calls that are needed for the external table, at least thats what I assume. You would need to check the routing from the Redshift VPC into the Glue VPC.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue and somehow I managed to resolve it.
This error caused when you enable Enhanced VPC routing in your cluster.

By default Glue endpoint uses default security group.
As error starting "glue.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", you need to enable DNS hostnames and DNS resolution for your VPC.
Also add inbound rule for port number 443 which is for https in default security group with source as Redshift's security group.

listing few links which helped me:

[+]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-interface-endpoints.html

[+]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html#vpce-interface-limitations

[+]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/spectrum-enhanced-vpc.html#spectrum-enhanced-vpc-considerations

"Access to AWS Glue or Amazon Athena
Redshift Spectrum accesses your data catalog in AWS Glue or Athena. Another option is to use a dedicated Hive metastore for your data catalog.

To enable access to AWS Glue or Athena, configure your VPC with an internet gateway or NAT gateway. Configure your VPC security groups to allow outbound traffic to the public endpoints for AWS Glue and Athena. Alternatively, you can configure an interface VPC endpoint for AWS Glue to access your AWS Glue Data Catalog. When you use a VPC interface endpoint, communication between your VPC and AWS Glue is conducted within the AWS network."

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this error message is having enabled **Enhanced VPC** on your Redshift Cluster.

As per documentation https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-enhanced-vpc-routing/ enabling Enhanced VPC might impact Unload / Copy commands. Here you are trying to create an external schema and one of the potential reason for this error is having enabled this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Enhanced VPC:

- Create VPC Endpoints Interface for: S3, Glue and, if using: LakeFormation, Athena.
- Create a VPC Endpoint Gateway for S3
- Ensure all endpoints have ingress 443 from the security group of Redshift
- Ensure Redshift has egress to the endpoints
- Check the routing table has routing to **S3 Gateway** prefix (not just IP to the S3 interface)
- Check DNS in the VPC

Answer (score -1):

The security group associated with the Redshift cluster needs to have `egress` configured for enabling outbound traffic.

Example `egress` configuration:

- from port: `0`
- to port: `0`
- protocol: `-1` (all protocols)
- CIDR IP: `"0.0.0.0/0"`

References

1. [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-security-group-egress.html)

Comment: Don't open redshift egress to 0.0.0.0/0, that will allow anyone to export data to internet if there is a NAT gateway.